# How to edit, add, retrieve and update info with javascript on Directus collection?

Tags: javascript, html-table, directus

I am currently working on an app that acts as a leader board. It now retrieves info and displays it in a table. I would like to know how to add and update the directus database in realtime with  HTML inputs and Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use The Directus Javascript SDK @ https://v8.docs.directus.io/guides/js-sdk.html#reference to edit, add, retrieve, and update a collection.

Comment: the link is broken